# BackSpace Key is Not Working in TextBox (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

Below is my code to restrict the data entry into textbox to numbers only upto two decimal places. However backspace key is not working while removing the data entered in the textbox.

```
Private Sub txtbasicsalary_keypress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtbasicsalary.KeyPress

    If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = "." Then
        e.Handled = True
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." And txtbasicsalary.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
        e.Handled = True
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = "." Then
        e.Handled = False
    ElseIf e.KeyChar = ControlChars.Back Then
        e.Handled = False
    ElseIf Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        If txtbasicsalary.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
            If txtbasicsalary.Text.Length >= txtbasicsalary.Text.IndexOf(".") + 3 Then  'replace 2 for greater numbers after decimal point
                e.Handled = True
                txtconveyance.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Please review and suggest.

Thanks 
Salman.

Comment: If restricting the input is that important (versus validation) why not use a NumericUpDown?

Comment: The first If statement also matches a backspace, easy to see with the debugger.

Comment: I don't use the debugger. I only write perfect code but I like to ask when it doesn't work. I mean, I've tried for hours and hours. I'll just ask before going to bed and when I wake up I'll get the answer. Debugger? It wasn't on the install list. I think Microsoft made an error and didn't install it with VS. Nah! I'm perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem a couple of weeks ago.
I edited your code! and checked it.
Now it's working Perfectly.
Enjoy it!
In addition you can download full working project form [here](http://oranusnovin.com/dl_files/Projects/back_key_oranusnovin.com.zip)

```
 Private Sub txtbasicsalary_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtbasicsalary.KeyPress
    If Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) And Not e.KeyChar = "." Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    If e.KeyChar = "." And txtbasicsalary.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
        e.Handled = True
    End If
    If e.KeyChar = "." Then
        e.Handled = False
    End If
    If e.KeyChar = Chr(Keys.Back) Then
        e.Handled = False
    End If
    If Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) Then
        If txtbasicsalary.Text.IndexOf(".") <> -1 Then
            If txtbasicsalary.Text.Length >= txtbasicsalary.Text.IndexOf(".") + 3 Then  'replace 2 for greater numbers after decimal point
                e.Handled = True
                txtconveyance.Focus()
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```